# Receber diversos valores e imprimir apenas os 3 maiores em c

Tags: c, if, else

Olá, tenho uma atividade a ser feita em que consiste em ir recebendo valores e só parar de recebe-los ao digitar -1, depois o programa deve exibir os 3 maiores valores digitados como se fosse um ranking de primeiro, segundo e terceiro lugar.Eu  quebrei bastante a cabeça e consegui escrever o programa, recebo todos valores, porem na hora de imprimir ele sempre mostra -1 nas 3 casas de impressão(-1 é o comando que para o laço para receber os valores)Acredito que seja um erro bem leve que está comprometendo o programa.Grato pela compreensão.A atividade descreve que não deve ser utilizado vetores.Antes que perguntem o nome das variáveis plu,slu e tlu são pra representar primeiro segundo e terceiro lugar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int pon = 0, plu, slu, tlu;

  while (pon != -1)
  {
    printf("Insira a pontuacao dos jogadores\n");
    scanf("%d", &pon);
    plu = pon ;
    slu = pon ;
    tlu = pon ;
  }

  if (plu >= slu)   
    if (slu >= tlu)
      printf(" 1 Lugar %d\n 2 Lugar %d\n 3 Lugar %d\n",plu,slu,tlu);
    else 
      if (plu >= tlu)
        printf(" 1 Lugar %d\n 3 Lugar %d\n 2 Lugar %d\n", plu, tlu, slu);
      else
        printf(" 3 Lugar %d\n 1 Lugar %d\n 2 Lugar %d\n", tlu, plu, slu);
      else
        if (slu >= tlu)
          if (plu >= tlu)
            printf(" 2 Lugar %d\n 1 Lugar %d\n 3 Lugar %d\n", slu, plu, tlu);   
          else
            printf(" 2 Lugar %d\n 3 Lugar %d\n 1 Lugar %d\n", slu, tlu, plu);
        else
          printf(" 3 Lugar %d\n 2 Lugar %d\n 1 Lugar %d\n", tlu, slu, plu);

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Seria bom identa seu código, iria facilitar bastante a leitura. Pelo que vejo, seu loop não faz nada, quando o usuário digitar `-1` e parar, o valor atribuido as variáveis `plu`, `slu`, `tlu` será sempre `-1` por que foi a última entrada do usuário

Comment: Da maneira como você fez o resultado será -1, -1 e -1.  Ao ler uma nova pontuação você tem que verificar se ela se encaixa em uma das 3 pontuações máximas e deslocar as abaixo delas colocando-a no devido lugar. Não precisa fazer este bando de testes ao final, basta imprimir os 3 valores.

Comment: a respeito de:  `main()`  existem apenas duas assinaturas válidas para o `main ()` Elas são: `int main (void)` e `int main (inc argc, char * argv [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. primeiro erro:

o motivo de estar dando sempre -1 é que voce le a opção em seguida armazena nas variaveis e so depois de armazenar ou não nelas vai ser verificado se é -1 ou n, então as variaveis sempre vai ser o ultimo numero que foi digitado,

2. segundo erro:

dentro do while vc esta atribuindo o mesmo valor para todas as colocações, tem que fazer verificações para ver se eles são maiores ou não que os valores anteriormente atribuidos

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main() 
    { 
        int pon = 0,
            plu = 0,
            slu = 0,
            tlu = 0;
        while (pon!=-1)
        {
            if(pon >= plu)
            {
                tlu = slu;
                slu = plu;
                plu = pon;
            }
            if(pon >= slu && pon < plu)
            {
                tlu = slu;
                slu = pon;
            }
            if(pon >= tlu && pon < slu)
                tlu = pon;
            printf("Insira a pontuacao dos jogadores\n");
            scanf("%d", &pon);
        }
        printf("%d | %d | %d \n", plu, slu, tlu);
    }
```

Comment: Esta solução possui um erro. Uma vez que forem entrados valores iguais eles serão atribuidos ao mesmo jogador, deixando o restante com 0. Exemplo: entrada: `2, 1, 1, -1  --> saída: 2, 1, 0 (erro)`. No caso houveram dois jogadores com placar 1, mas a solução apresenta apenas um.

Comment: @alandplm realmente tinha considerado que todos seriam diferente mas não tinha colocado o ```>= ``` ou inves apenas do ```> ``` para os casos de terem entradas iguais, corrigido

Answer (score 0):

Inicialize com um valor inválido (usei -1) e a cada leitura verifique se é um dos três primeiros, desloque os menores e coloque-o no devido lugar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pon = 0, plu=-1, slu=-1, tlu=-1;
    printf("Insira a pontuacao dos jogadores [-1 para encerrar]: ");
    scanf("%d", &pon);
    while (pon != -1) {
        if (pon > plu) {
            tlu = slu;
            slu = plu;
            plu = pon;
        }
        else {
            if (pon > slu) {
                tlu = slu;
                slu = pon;
            }
            else {
                if (pon > tlu) {
                    tlu = pon;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Insira a pontuacao dos jogadores [-1 para encerrar]: ");
        scanf("%d", &pon);
    }
    printf(" 1 Lugar %d\n 2 Lugar %d\n 3 Lugar %d\n", plu, slu, tlu);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção amigo realmente me ajudou muito , estava tanto tempo pensando nesse problema que minha cabeça ja não funcionava mais

Answer (score 0):

O principal erro no seu programa é que no loop principal ele apelas lê a entrada (pon) e sempre a atribui para as variáveis plu, slu e tlu. Logo, o último valor lido (-1) sempre estará armazenado nas três variáveis. As comparações têm de ser realizadas dentro do loop para saber quais são os três maiores valores.

A solução de @tredeneo acima possui um erro. Uma vez que forem entrados somente valores iguais eles serão todos atribuidos ao mesmo jogador deixando o restante com 0. Ex:

```
entrada: 1, 1, -1  --> saída: 1, 0, 0 (erro)
entrada: 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1 --> saída: 2, 1, 0 (erro)
```

Segue abaixo uma versão que fiz do programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int entrada, x1, x2, x3;
    x1 = x2 = x3 = 0;

    do {
        printf("Insira a pontuacao dos jogadores\n");
        scanf("%d", &entrada);

        if (entrada == -1) {
            break;
        } else if (entrada > x1) {
            x3 = x2;
            x2 = x1;
            x1 = entrada;
        } else if (entrada > x2 && entrada <= x1) {
            x3 = x2;
            x2 = entrada;
        } else if (entrada > x3 && entrada <= x2) {
            x3 = entrada;
        }
    } while (entrada != -1);

    printf(" 1 Lugar %d\n 2 Lugar %d\n 3 Lugar %d\n", x1, x2, x3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementação com teste do scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n, pon, plu = -1, slu = -1, tlu = -1;

  do
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* pontos (-1 para fim): ");

    n = scanf("%d", &pon);
    scanf("%*[^\n]");

    if (n != 1)
    {
      printf("* entrada de dados invalida!\n");
      pon = 0;
    }

    else if (pon > plu)
    {
      tlu = slu;
      slu = plu;
      plu = pon;
    }

    else if (pon > slu)
    {
      tlu = slu;
      slu = pon;
    }

    else if (pon > tlu)
    {
      tlu = pon;
    }

    printf("* plu=%d slu=%d tlu=%d\n", plu, slu, tlu);
  } while (pon != -1);

  printf("*\n");
}
```

Teste:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./383228
*
* pontos (-1 para fim): 12
* plu=12 slu=-1 tlu=-1
*
* pontos (-1 para fim): 5
* plu=12 slu=5 tlu=-1
*
* pontos (-1 para fim): 7
* plu=12 slu=7 tlu=5
*
* pontos (-1 para fim): v
* entrada de dados invalida!
* plu=12 slu=7 tlu=5
*
* pontos (-1 para fim): 6 7777777777777777777
* plu=12 slu=7 tlu=6
*
* pontos (-1 para fim): -1
* plu=12 slu=7 tlu=6
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```